# Приложение крашится при запуске, в логах NullPointerException

Tags: java, android-studio

Проблема такая - простое приложение вылетает с ошибкой при попытке запустить в эмуляторе, в логах вот что:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.crowcounter/com.example.android.crowcounter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

---

Вот Java-код:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button mCrowsCounterButton;
    private int mCount = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mCrowsCounterButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonCount);

        mCrowsCounterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                helloTextView.setText("Я насчитал " + ++mCount + " ворон");
            }
        });
    }
    TextView helloTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    public void onClick(View view){
        helloTextView.setText("Hello Kitty!");
    }
}
```

А это XML:

```
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.crowcounter.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:text="@string/hello_text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonHello"
        android:layout_width="142dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="238dp"
        android:background="@color/colorButtonBackground"
        android:onClick=""
        android:text="@string/hello_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCount"
        android:layout_width="142dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:background="@color/colorButtonBackground"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/crow_count" />


</LinearLayout>
```

На всякий случай скриншот[image: На всякий случай скриншот]

Comment: Покажите свой манифест, такое ощущение, что Activity не декларирован в манифесте

Comment: Почитайте лог ошибки, чётко написано, что вы пытаетесь найти view которого не существует.

Comment: @Евгений нет, ошибка совсем о другом говорит.

Answer (score 0):

У вас `TextView helloTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)` отрабатывает до инициализации `Activity`.

**Все** `findViewById` должны вызываться **после** `setContentView`.

Вынесите получение ссылки на `helloTextView` в `onCreate`:

```
TextView helloTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mCrowsCounterButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonCount);
    helloTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    mCrowsCounterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            helloTextView.setText("Я насчитал " + ++mCount + " ворон");
        }
    });
}
```